# How can I update data all at once with BigQuery API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I saw in this article(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-update-with-dml) how to update data via DML.
(For reference, I am developing using Java and Spring Boot.)

An additional question is whether it is possible to send json data via BigQuery API and use it for batch updates.

example json data:

```
[{"id":1, "name":"a"}, {"id":1, "name":"b"}, {"id":2, "name":"a"}]
```

And the update query I want to run is below. (The PK for this table is "id" and "name")

```
update table A
set A.value = 'test'
where (A.id, A.name) in (
    ...In this part, I want to use the above json data as a condition...
)
```

Is it possible to process these queries with "BigQuery.query" method? Or, I wonder if there is another way.

Or is there only a way to create an update query for the above json data one by one and execute it with conditions? (like the query below)

```
update table A
set A.value = 'test'
where A.id = 1
and A.name = 'a'
...
...
update table A
set A.value = 'test'
where A.id = 1
and A.name = 'b'
...
...
update table A
set A.value = 'test'
where A.id = 2
and A.name = 'a'
```

Comment: BigQuery has a lot of functions to work with JSON in the query, take a look and see if helps: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#function_overview

Comment: @DamiãoMartins
thx for your answer. Looking at the attached document, it seems that I can use UNNEST to convert JSON Data into a table. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi @eastglow , If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#function_overview) to retrieve and transform JSON data. GCP has introduced new features to work with JSON data type with some limitations but can be used to create JSON values, insert JSON data along with querying. Using this you can ingest semi-structured JSON into BigQuery. This feature lets you not adhere to fixed schemas and data types which makes it more flexible.For more information on JSON data type, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data).